# use kartik editable without form submit ; just to change value

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I want to use kartik editable plugin in gridview but without submitting form, it should just change the value visibly

Comment: I don't understand you ( What it mean, "change the value visibly"?

Comment: I mean form doesn't submit , but value of editable element is changed

Comment: @frops do you got question ? I just want to use it for viewing purpose . nothing happens on server side

Comment: But this kartik editable using for save data via ajax. Why use this widget only for view?